# Check if 2 trees have the same structure

Tags: c++11

Only passing an object of type BST NOT of type Node,the logic here is wrong i want some help with it, it always return false

```
bool BST<T>::similarStructure(BST<T>& Tree2) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        cout << "tree is empty\n";
        return;
    }

    StackArray<node<T>> *s1, *s2; // s1 for traversal,, s2 for printing

    s1->Push(root);
    s2->Push(tree2.root);
    while (!s1.IsEmpty() &&!s2.isempty()) {
        node<T> n = s1->Pop();
        node<T> n1=s2->Pop();
        if (n->right != NULL && n1->right!=NULL){
            s1.Push(n->right);
            s2.Push(n1->right); }
         else{
           return false;}

        if (n->left != NULL && n->left!=NULL){
            s1.Push(n->left); 
            s2.Push(n1->left);}
        else{
            return false;}

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where's the instance of ```StackArray<node<T>>```? It seems that in this code you just defined two pointer ```s1``` and ```s2``` without initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

Take the simplest situation as example, that the lhs tree and rhs tree both have only one node.

Inside the while loop, when hit the first condition expression, `if (n->right != NULL && n1->right!=NULL)`, since `n->right == NULL`, the expression evaluate false value, thus return false for this function.

Comment: Yes you are right it should be n1, but still same logical mistake